# C init an array of chars in a function or should i pass it as a parameter

Tags: c, arrays, function, char, c99

i have a function takes a char pointer, like this one:

```
void func(char *string);
```

My wish is to change the passed char array in this way:

func("User") -> Hello, User!

What is the better way to solve this task?

Option#1; -> use an other char array  -> temp (will be declared once)

```
void func(char *string, char *temp){
    sprintf(temp, "Hello, %s!", string);
}
```

and use after temp.

Option#2; -> use temp as local variable (should be declared each time in the function's body)

```
void func(char *string){
    char temp[512];
    sprintf(temp, "Hello, %s!", string);
    sprintf(string, "%s", temp);
    // or strcpy(string, temp); string[strlen(temp)]=0;
}
```

The problem is the function is called often. Does the second option reduce significantly the performance? There are other options to solve this task?

Comment: Define "often". `sprintf()` is already as slow as heck. But it's still not slow enough to be worth worrying about usually. "Performance" is something that people worry about too much. First benchmark and profile, and **only then** try to optimize. Also, `snprintf()` (we don't need moar buffer overflows plox)

Comment: This function is used to create a string message will be send from server to client using UPD sockets. Example: >> %Username% said: message. So it will be used often ^^.

Answer (score 2):

The first option is the better of the two. The second will invoke undefined behavior if used with a string literal, since you can't overwrite them. Of course it wouldnt' make any sense anyway, how would you expect to retreive the overwritten literal?

It would be better with buffer overflow protection and proper `const` for the input string of course:

```
void func(const char *string, char *out, size_t out_max)
{
  snprintf(out, out_max, "Hello, %s!", string);
}
```

Most systems should have `snprintf()` by now.

Comment: Exactly.  If your system lacks snprintf(), sell it as an antique.

Comment: return type mismatch: snprintf() returns a (signed) int. func() returns void.

Comment: @wildplasser D'oh! Thanks. That `return` shouldn't have been there.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

Take a string with size of `"Hello! User" + 1` and initialize it with `"Hello! "`

`char string[20] = "Hello! ";` (let)

Then everytime take input at `string + 7`. (`7` is length of `"Hello! "`)

`scanf("%s", string + 7);`

If you want to use the `"User"` string only at anytime after that, then `string + 7` will always be pointing to it.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be a big difference in performance partly because it's a small function and because the compiler knows how to optimize those types of things, in general the best practice is to declare it once. Since you don't know how long the username is going to be you have to do some memory allocation. I would suggest doing something like this:

```
void func(char* name) {
   char* hello = "Hello! ";
   //allocate memory for the whole string
   char* tmp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(name)+strlen(hello)+1));
   //construct the string
   strcpy(tmp, hello);
   strcat(tmp, name);
   //print it
   printf("%s\n", tmp);
   //discard of the space you used
   free(tmp);
}
```

This way you'll make sure that you have enough memory and performancewise i think printf is the slowest operation there.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options already; but since you stated you really want the highest performance solution, maybe the following is useful - you create a single function that keeps being re-used (rather than hard-coding the template string, you pass it in; that way you only have one such function, instead of one function for every possible output). I am pretty sure that a `snprintf` function with a `%s` argument does something akin to a `memcpy` on a half-decent compiler, so this should be about as efficient as you can be. At any rate the job of producing the output to the screen will be **far slower** than the job of generating the string. And remember that **code that is easy to maintain** will, in the long run, always be the right option.

There are two ways to do this - you can create an actual function like so:

```
void create_output(char* subThis, char* intoThis, char* outputThat, int n){
    snprintf(outputThat, n, intoThis, subThis);
}
```

Or you can use `#define` to alias one name to another. This has the advantage that you can use a more natural order of parameters whilst using `snprintf` under the covers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_OUT 100
#define create_output(a,b,c,d) snprintf((c),(d),(b),(a))

//void create_output(char* subThis, char* intoThis, char* outputThat, int n)

int main(void) {
    char username[]="Fred";
    char template[]="Hello %s";
    char output[MAX_OUT];

    create_output(username, template, output, MAX_OUT);
    // and show that it works:
    printf("%s\n", output);
}
```

You could even make the user's life simpler if you keep your output buffer always available for just this purpose: in the below, the `#define` uses the comma operator to execute the `snprintf` function but return the pointer to the result, `OUTPUT` - which is a buffer with global scope that is defined just once. This may look a bit like a hack, but it generates the functionality you ask for in about as efficient and flexible a manner as possible (minimal overhead - a lot of the work is done at compile time).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_OUT 100
char OUTPUT[MAX_OUT];

#define create_output(a,b) (snprintf(OUTPUT,MAX_OUT,(b),(a)), OUTPUT)

// apparent prototype:
// char* create_output(char* subThis, char* intoThis)
// it returns a pointer to the location where the string is stored

int main(void) {
    char username[]="Fred";
    char template[]="Hello %s";
    char *output;

    output = create_output(username, template);
    // and show that it works:
    printf("%s\n", output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void func(const char *string, char *outbuff){
    const char *p = "Hello, ";
    while(*p)
        *outbuff++ = *p++;
    p = string;
    while(*p)
        *outbuff++ = *p++;
    p = "!";
    while(*outbuff++ = *p++);
}
```

Comment: Please also provide a brief explanation.

Comment: It is believed that the person who prepared the area for output from editing the original as good performance. Program to merely copy simply.